# Adding google adsense to my ReactJS app without any BACKEND

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-ads-script

The code snippet in the google adsense page, i paste in my reactJS website by creating a new file/component, here is the code: NOTE: please tell me if this is correct.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const AdComponent = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js';
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    const ins = document.createElement('ins');
    ins.className = 'adsbygoogle';
    ins.style.display = 'block';
    ins.style.textAlign = 'center';
    ins.setAttribute('data-ad-client', '########');
    ins.setAttribute('data-ad-slot', '########');
    ins.setAttribute('data-ad-format', 'auto');
    document.getElementById('ad-container').appendChild(ins);

    (window.adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="ad-container" />
  );
};

export default AdComponent;
```

i create a new file called AdComponent.js, and paste this code snippet.

and render it in my App.js file

```
import AdComponent from './AdComponent'

function App() {
   return (
     <div classname='app>
        <AdComponent />
     </div>
   );
};
```

Im expecting to see that you correct my code, and say this is wrong or correct.

**NOTE: I haven't paste the OTHER code snippet in  tag in my index.html.
NOTE: I use ChatGPT to do this, so if its wrong just say it, im trying to see if this right or wrong.
NOTE: I didnt use any third party packages, so please don't add any 3rd party packages, im trying to keep it simple**

Comment: Do you have a specific question about this code?  Have you tried it and is it not working?  If so, what is the error or problem?  Right now it seems like you are just asking for general code review, which is not really the purpose of StackOverflow, especially if the code is working just fine, so I would ask that you update your post with a specific question and a bit more focus, if possible.

Comment: Code from ChatGPT is not accepted as input on any of the Stack Exchange web sites. If this code was written by ChatGPT please delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

[React-helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet) is the solution!

Just install and add the Adsense header on the component you want. Also if you need to check if the browser has Adblocker, use this:

```
export function createBaitElement() {
    const bait = document.createElement("div");
    bait.setAttribute(
        "class",
        "pub_300x250 pub_300x250m pub_728x90 text-ad textAd text_ad text_ads text-ads text-ad-links advertisement ad-text adSense adBlock adContent adBanner"
    );
    bait.setAttribute(
        "style",
        "width: 1px !important; height: 1px !important; position: absolute !important; left: -10000px !important; top: -1000px !important;"
    );
    return bait;
}

export function doesElementIsBlocked(elem: HTMLDivElement) {
    if (
        elem.offsetParent === null ||
        elem.offsetHeight === 0 ||
        elem.offsetLeft === 0 ||
        elem.offsetTop === 0 ||
        elem.offsetWidth === 0 ||
        elem.clientHeight === 0 ||
        elem.clientWidth === 0
    ) {
        return true;
    }
    if (window.getComputedStyle !== undefined) {
        const elemCS = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null);
        if (
            elemCS &&
            (elemCS.getPropertyValue("display") === "none" ||
                elemCS.getPropertyValue("visibility") === "hidden")
        ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

export default function detectDomAdblocker() {
    // that's a legacy Ad Block Plus check I suppose ?
    // I don't think this attribute is set anymore, but I am keeping it anyway
    if (window.document.body.getAttribute("abp") !== null) {
        return true;
    }
    // try to lure adblockers into a trap
    const bait = createBaitElement();
    window.document.body.appendChild(bait);
    const detected = doesElementIsBlocked(bait);
    window.document.body.removeChild(bait);
    return detected;
}
```

The final implementation is like this

```
function LayoutDefault() {

    const { user, token } = useSession()

    const [showAds, setShowAds] = useState(false)


    const { isZoomActive, isFooterVisible } = useSelector(
        (state: RootState) => state.zoom
    )

    const [adBlockDetected, setAdBlockDetected] = useState(false);


    useEffect(() => {
        setAdBlockDetected(detectDomAdblocker());
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        setAdBlockDetected(detectDomAdblocker());
    }, [window.location.pathname]);

    //TODO: Add ablock logic

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!token) return;
        if (canShowAds(user)) {
            setShowAds(true)
        }
    }, [user]);


    return (
        <>
            <Helmet>
                {
                    showAds && (
                        <script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
                            crossOrigin="anonymous"></script>
                    )
                }
            </Helmet>
     ... your code
    </>
```